# How to make a plane with cloth physics, stick to another mesh like a tape?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm simply trying to figure out how does cloth sim work, by trying to make a plane stick to nearby sphere. Bizzarely, it doesn't work, at all. The spheres collisions have friction set to 80, both "cloths" have "shrink" vert group, but the plane just slides off it. Only circle does stick to the sphere. Difference between these is that, the circle was extruded out of the sphere.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain to me, what am I doing wrong ?

Edit:[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve, but without using pin group, so that the green line would deform with the deformation of the ball (For example, when the ball stretches, the cloth doesn't clip inside it)

Comment: can u pls show a sketch or picture what you are trying to achieve? Pin group might be what you want but it is not clear to me how your result should look like...!?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/4SRypbvfItDU

This is what I'm trying to achieve, but without using pin group, but a shrink factor

Comment: Maybe a *ShrinkWrap* could work for the green part? I don't think this will work without a pin group because the *Friction* value does not work like glue.

Comment: Figured things out at this point.